# Find pandas Groupby with NaNs in all columns

Tags: python, pandas

Say we have a DataFrame set up as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['ID'] = [432, 601,  601, 383, 887, 887, 944,  68, 195, 724, 408, 351]
df['Details'] = [362,  85, 338, 332, 712, 932, 797, 365, 837,  66, 721, 695]
df['Tests'] = [769, np.nan, np.nan,  np.nan, 988, 496,   7, 408, np.nan, 417, 287, 723]
df['Size'] = [877,  np.nan,  np.nan, np.nan, 550, 967, 646, 654,  76, 185, np.nan, 635]

df['GroupID']=0
unique_ids = df.drop_duplicates(['ID']).index
df.loc[unique_ids, 'GroupID'] = 1
df['GroupID'] = df['GroupID'].cumsum()
```

resultant df:

```
    ID  Details Tests   Size    GroupID
0   432 362     769.0   877.0   1
1   601 85      NaN     NaN     2
2   601 338     NaN     NaN     2
3   383 332     NaN     NaN     3
4   887 712     988.0   550.0   4
5   887 932     496.0   967.0   4
6   944 797     7.0     646.0   5
7   68  365     408.0   654.0   6
8   195 837     NaN     76.0    7
9   724 66      417.0   185.0   8
10  408 721     287.0   NaN     9
11  351 695     723.0   635.0   10
```

How can I find where  `['Tests', 'Size']` are `NaN` for all members of that group (i.e. have the same `GroupID`). For this example the answer should be `GroupID = (2,3)`, or `ID = 601, 383`.

My data is mainly of dtype `object` - so mostly strings (so `Tests` and `Size` would be strings).

Comment: I am thinking of something along the lines of:
`all_null = dflow[['Tests','Size']].isnull().all(axis=1)`
`dflow['all_null'] = all_null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way:

```
df_out = df[df.groupby('GroupID')[['Tests','Size']].transform('count').sum(1).eq(0)]
```

And the same logic as below to get GroupID or ID

Note: `count` does not count NaN values so we check the count equal to zero and sum to see if all in that group are NaN.

---

On way is to use:

```
df_out = df.groupby('GroupID').filter(lambda x: x[['Tests','Size']].isnull().all().all())

    ID  Details  Tests  Size  GroupID
1  601       85    NaN   NaN        2
2  601      338    NaN   NaN        2
3  383      332    NaN   NaN        3
```

Then,

```
df_out.ID.unique().tolist()
```

Output:

```
[601, 383]
```

OR

```
df_out.GroupID.unique().tolist()
```

Output:

```
[2, 3]
```

Comment: That is a good way to do it, but the filter method is really slow for my dataset

Comment: @AH See mod see if that is any better.

Comment: Much better, 9.54 ms ± 393 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the , [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) ,and using thresh here, it will give back how many non-nan value required

```
df.GroupID[~df.GroupID.isin(df.dropna(thresh=df.shape[1]-1).GroupID)].unique()
Out[204]: array([2, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: @Nae added  :-) ~